# Failed to connect to example.ru port 443: Connection refused

Tags: node.js, nginx, curl

Есть сервер с nginx.

При обращении через curl или через nodejs на этот же сервер
curl https://example.ru/test

Возникает ошибка
(7) Failed to connect to example.ru port 443: Connection refused

В чем может быть проблема?

1. На http и https ошибка та же
2. Файрволлов нету

UPD:
Если так, то ошибка 404
curl http://localhost/main/testpage

**Конфиг nginx**

```
upstream php {
        server unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;
    server_name example.ru www.example.ru;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    server_name example.ru www.example.ru;

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.ru/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.ru/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
        index index.php;
    }
    location @rewrite {
            rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
            fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_ignore_client_abort on;
            fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME $http_host;
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. Какой IP-адрес у доменного имени example.ru?
2. Какой IP-адрес у машины, на которой выполняется команда curl?  
3. Подразумевается, что curl обратится на веб-сервер, работающий на том же хосте, на котором выполняется curl?

Answer (score -1):

Проблема оказалась в не правильном адресе в файле `/etc/hosts`